# Howto provide a Jaxb Mapper for Soap Webservice without annotations

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

I have a REST server based in Javax WS-RS. I used a Jackson JAXB for serialization so I have a one mapper for all classes

And now, I need create the same webservice but based in SOAP. I need configurate the options for JAXB and all tutorial that I see use Annotations, so I should modified a lot of classes.

Any way to provide by code a mapper for all classes instead of classes or packages annotations?